# How do I target a specific field from a nested array in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular

I am a complete novice in programming. For one of my school projects, I have a JSON nested array which I retrieved from my ASP.Net API, and I need to get the `speakerID` value from this array and push it into another array. How do I do this in angular?
(also my first time posting in StackOverflow so pardon the format please)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you stored the response in variable `data`. Then you can get all speaker ids like this:

```js
const data = [{
    speakers: [{
      speakerID: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    speakers: [{
      speakerID: 2
    }]
  },
];

let speakerIds = data.reduce((res, item) => {
  let i = item.speakers.map((speaker) =>
    speaker.speakerID);
  return res.concat(i);
}, []);

console.log(speakerIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

following Harsh Saini's solution, I think you could just use flatMap instead of Reduce

```
const data = [{
    speakers: [{
      speakerID: 1
    }]
  },
  {
    speakers: [{
      speakerID: 2
    }]
  },
];

const result = data.flatMap((val) => {
  return val.speakers.map((nestedval) => nestedval.speakerID);
});
```